# MVC pasting HTML to excel

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, excel

I have a html content which I would like to export as excel file. My function for exporting to excel looks like this:

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel(string htmlToExport)
{
  using (ExcelPackage ep = new ExcelPackage())
  {
    string fileTemplate = "test.xlsx";

    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/") + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["templatePath"] + fileTemplate, FileMode.Open))
    {
      ep.Load(stream);
    }

    ExcelWorksheet ws = ep.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", fileTemplate); 
    return File(ep.GetAsByteArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

  }
}
```

Is there a way to paste html to excel file? If I do this manually, everything is OK. I would like to do this on the server side and return excel file with pasted html inside. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "pasted HTML" and how is it not working?

Comment: If I copy - paste HTML to excel file, it looks just fine. I would like to do this in code.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible. My code sample is below;

```
        public ActionResult BankAccountReport(BankAccountsInfoFilter bankAccountsInfoFilter)
        {      
            var bankAccountInfos = service.GetBankAccounts(bankAccountsInfoFilter);

            DetailReportExport(bankAccountInfos);

            return new EmptyResult();
        }

        [NonAction]
        public void DetailReportExport(List<BankAccountViewModel> bankAccountInfos)
        {
            string html = RenderPartialViewToString("_BankAccountDetailReport", bankAccountInfos);

            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=BankAccountInfoDetailReport.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
            Response.AddHeader("content-language", "tr-TR");
            Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
            Response.Write(html);
        }
```

Comment: This works... only problem is warning when opening saved file. Do I have to change something if I want .xlsx extension? (of course, I've changed extension in filename). Xlsx can not be opened. I can successfully save and open .xls (with warning).